# Posting in several tastypie resources simultaneously

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

Here's what I'm trying to do :

The user creates an Event in my application. Here's the model :

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    place = models.TextField(null=True)
    confirmed = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    organizer_part = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

Right after that, it posts the different people invited to this event, and the different dates that the user chose. Here are the models :

```
class EventDate(models.Model):
    """Correspondances date-event"""
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    date = models.BigIntegerField()


class EventPeople(models.Model):
    """Correspondances personne-event"""
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    answer = models.BooleanField()
    participation = models.NullBooleanField()
```

I'd like to fill those three models in only one request. So far I have to make three requests. I can't see how I could possibly do it.

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resource that should work with your models is:

```
class EventResource(ModelResource):
    event_dates = fields.ToManyField(EventDateResource, 'event_dates')
    event_peoples = field.ToManyField(EventPeopleResource, 'event_peoples')
    class Meta:
          queryset = Event.objects.all()
```

Also you have to create simple EventDateResource and EventPeopleResource.

One one more change in yout models, you need to add related_names:

```
class EventDate(models.Model):
    """Correspondances date-event"""
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='event_dates')
    date = models.BigIntegerField()


class EventPeople(models.Model):
    """Correspondances personne-event"""
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='event_peoples')
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    answer = models.BooleanField()
    participation = models.NullBooleanField()
```

Comment: I'm going to try this right now. So I should be able to send json data that looks like this : {'event_field1':'data1','event_field2':'data2', ... , event_dates :[{event:event,date:187675878000},{event:event,date:187675878000}], etc... ? And it will populate all the tables at once ?

Comment: I'm getting the following error : "'Event' object has no attribute 'event_dates'"

Comment: Also, if I understand it right, it's going to create a join table, and I'd like to avoid that, since my EventDate resource is already kind of a join table, with the event foreign key.